# IP address of the remote database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I registered on http://apex.oracle.com/ and created a test schema there, now I am trying to connect to it from unix command line using tool called sqlline, I am trying to connect like this:

```
 sqlline
 !connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@apex.oracle.com:1521:MY_DB username password oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

But something goes wrong, do you know is possible to know the exact address of my schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the database is not directly accessible, but only through the web interface.